# How to add div class in custom addField form function in magento?

Tags: html, magento

I have created a custom module with some fields. I have used Varien_Data_Form for creating form with fields. I have added radios buttons, I just want to add one `<div>` between those radio buttons. I don't know to do that.

My radio button code for form:

```
   $productField=$fieldset->addField('radio2', 'radios', array(
      'name'      => 'house_building',
      'value'  => '1',
      'class'  => 'house_building',
      'values' => array(
                        array('value'=>'1','label'=>'House','id'=>'house'),
                        array('value'=>'2','label'=>'Building','id'=>'house'),
                   ),
    ));
```

I have printed this form in view page using:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("suggestions_edit_form") ?>
```

I got 2 radio button in the following format:

```
    <div class="value">
   <input name="house_building" class="house_building" value="1" id="radio21" checked="checked" type="radio"><label class="inline" for="radio21">House</label>
  <input name="house_building" class="house_building" value="2" id="radio22" type="radio"><label class="inline" for="radio22">Building</label>     
      </div>
```

Now I want to change this is in the following format with extra `div` tags:

```
    <div class="value">
    <div class="field-container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="radio21" value="1" class="house_building validation-passed" name="house_building">
    <label for="radio21" class="inline">House</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field-container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <input type="radio" id="radio22" value="2" class="house_building validation-passed" name="house_building">
    <label for="radio22" class="inline">Building</label>          
    </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know how to do this?

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: you can use jQuery to replace your code once html has been loaded

Comment: I found the solution. I will post now.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a helper for that particular radio button alone:

My helper file:

```
   class NextBits_Marketplace_Block_Form_Helper_Type extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text
        {
            /**
             * Validation classes for weight field which corresponds to DECIMAL(12,4) SQL type
             *
             * @param array $attributes
             */
            public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
            {
                parent::__construct($attributes);        
            }   
            public function getElementHtml()
            {                       
                $html = '<div class="field-container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">';
                $html .="<input type=radio checked=checked id=radio21 value=1 class=house_building validation-passed name=house_building>
                <label for=radio21 class=inline>House</label></div>";
                $html .='<div class="field-container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">';
                $html .="<input type=radio id=radio22 value=2 class=house_building validation-passed name=house_building>
                <label for=radio22 class=inline>Building</label>";
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= $this->getAfterElementHtml();
                return $html;
            }
        }
```

I just called this helper in my Varien_Data_Form addfield:

```
    $fieldset->addType('type', 'NextBits_Marketplace_Block_Form_Helper_Type');

    $fieldset->addField('type', 'type', array(
        'name'      => 'house_building',
        'value'  => '1',
        'class'  => 'house_building',
        'container_class' => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 customer-profile-radio'
    ));
```

Now I got the output with added div tags.